# Socket fails to accept a client?

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to get my feet wet with network programming. I have created a server, that accepts a connection from a web client.

At some point (I can not recall when) it broke, and for the life of me, I can not get it fixed.

Could someone at least provide me with some pointers? (No pun intended)

I have tried all there is, read the whole web, including the [gnu](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Accepting-Connections.html) [c](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Socket-Addresses.html#Socket-Addresses) [library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Listening.html#Listening) [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Transferring-Data.html#Transferring-Data) (I am on linux) but still no luck.

***EDIT:*** Description of the problem: My client software manages to connect, however the server software doesn't report on that, and seems to get stuck at the accept() function.

My code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "lib/error.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socketfd = 0, connfd = 0; // socket, and connection file descriptors
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; // struct that will get filled with host info
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr; // struct that will get filled with peer info
    int status; // Used for various status controling and error messaging throughout the program

    char sendBuff[1025]; // buffer to allow for storage of items to be sent
    socklen_t cli_size = sizeof(cli_addr);
    time_t ticks;

    socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Creating a socket
    if (socketfd == -1) error("Failed to create socket.", 4);

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); // zeroing out the location of serv_addr
    memset(&cli_addr, '0', sizeof(cli_addr)); // zeroing out the location of serv_addr
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); // zeroing out the locaiton of sendBuff

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

    status = bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if (status == -1) error("Failed to bind socket.", 4);

    listen(socketfd, 10);

    while(1)
    {
        connfd = accept(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, (socklen_t *) &cli_size);
        if (connfd == -1) error("Failed during accepting the peer connection at socket.", 3);

        printf("Client connected: %d:%d", cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, cli_addr.sin_port);

        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea if this is related at all, but your `memset` is not zeroing out memory - it is setting it to the ASCII value of the character `'0'`, which is very different.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Really? It wasn't the first time that I ever saw this, but never really studied it, and I thought it was zeroing out the memory. But I have to note that this `'0'` was putting me into thoughts.

Comment: Can you call `fflush(stdout)` right after the `printf` ?

Comment: @cnicutar Yes! And it returns: `Client connected: 50440384:34498`

Comment: @cnicutar So I guess this did it. Had no idea that fflush even existed. Just finished reading up on it. Write your comment as an answer, to allow me to select it as the answer to my problem

Comment: If you just added a `\n` (newline) to the `printf()` call, that should do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As speculated in the comments, the problem is buffering. In a nutshell, the client connects, `accept` returns a valid socket and `printf` is called but the output simply doesn't get onto the screen.

As Roddy mentioned, adding a newline **might fix it** because on many implementations `stdout` is line-buffered, i.e. when you write a newline it automatically flushes everything. However, that isn't required by the standard so the safest cleanest way to ensure the output does go to the device is `fflush`.

As Chris Hayes mentioned, you probably want `memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof serv_addr)` and you don't need the cast in `(socklen_t *) &cli_size`.